# Why a cylinder set with base in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can have a base in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as well?

Tags: measure-theory, intuition

Let define a cylinder set as:

$$\mathcal{C}(B_1 \times \dots \times B_n)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}|x_1 \in B_1 , \dots , x_n \in B_n \}$$

where $B_k \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for $k=1,2,...,n$ with base in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But, we can write also:

> $$\mathcal{C}(B_1 \times \dots \times B_n)=\mathcal{C}(B_1 \times
>  \dots \times B_n\times \mathbb{R})$$

with base in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

**Why is this statement true?**

Comment: Have you made an attempt?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes I made an attempt to understand why is this true and I read also in the book of Shiryaev but I couldn't figure out.

Comment: No proof is required. The equality is true by definition.

Comment: Can you find an element in the set denoted on LHS that is not in the set denoted on RHS? Can you find an element in the set denoted on RHS that is not in the set denoted on LHS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If $x\in A$ implies that $x\in B$ and $x\in B$ implies that $x\in A$ then we are allowed to conclude that $A=B$.

This because (according to the axiom of extensionality) sets are completely determined by their elements.